# Is this equivalent?

Tags: predicate-logic

Im having a dillema , is

> ∀x(p(x) -> ∃y n(y)) 
>   
>  and 
>   ∃x p(x) -> ∃y n(y)

equivalent?
it seems at all cases its the same, is it really equivalent?

Comment: No.  They are not not equivalent.  Suppose $p(7) \implies \exists y n(y)$ but $p(8) \not \implies \exists y n(y)$.  Then the second is true and the first is false.

Comment: but wait , how can ∃yn(y) be false at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please format your math with mathjax: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @fleablood can you clarify once more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A universal can be seen as kind of conjunction, that is, if $a,b,c,...$ denote the objects in your domain, then you can think of a universal like this:

$$\forall x \: P(x) \approx P(a) \land P(b) \land P(c) \land ...$$

I write $\approx$, since this is technically not a logical equivalence, but it does capture the semantics of the quantifier. As such, you can 'prove' the following law:

**Prenex Laws**

Where $P(x)$ is any formula and where $x$ is *not* a free variable in $Q$:

$$ \forall x \ P(x) \lor Q \Leftrightarrow \forall x (P(x) \lor Q)$$

'Proof':

$$\forall x (P(x) \lor Q) \approx$$

$$(P(a) \lor Q) \land (P(b) \lor Q) \land (P(c) \lor Q) \land ... \Leftrightarrow \text{(Distribution } \lor \text{ over } \land)$$

$$(P(a) \land P(b) \land P(c) \land ...) \lor Q \approx$$

$$\forall x \ P(x) \lor Q$$

With this, we can now prove your equivalence as well:

$$\forall x (p(x) \rightarrow \exists y \ n(y)) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Implication)}$$

$$\forall x (\neg p(x) \lor \exists y \ n(y)) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Prenex Law)}$$

$$\forall x \neg p(x) \lor \exists y \ n(y) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Quantifier Negation)}$$

$$\neg \exists x p(x) \lor \exists y \ n(y) \Leftrightarrow \text{ (Implication)}$$

$$\exists x p(x) \rightarrow \exists y \ n(y)$$

Answer (score 1):

I misread so ignor my comment.

The parenthesis is important.

$\forall x(p(x) \to \exists y n(y))$

Means for every $x$, if $p(x)$ then there exists a y so that $n(y)$.  So it might be possible that there are no $x$ so that $p(x)$.  But if any $x$ has $p(x)$ being true then there is a $y$ that $n(y)$ is true.

$\exists xp(x) \to \exists y n(y)$ means that if there is any $p$ so that $p(x)$ then there is a $y$ so that $n(y)$.

Those are the same.

Consider $p=$ went to college.  And $n$ lives in a pool.

So the first says, for every person, if that person went to college then there is a person who live in a pool.  Now maybe nobody went to college and no-one lives in a pool, but if anyone went to college, there's a person living in a pool.

The second says, if there is a person who went to college, then there is someone who lives in a pool.  Again maybe nobody went to college and no-one lives in a pool, but if anyone went to college, there's a person living in a pool.

They are equivalent.

Comment: Can we proof that it's equivalent with (de)constructing the first one into the second one? I'm having difficulty as the 2 seems very different